# How to calculate the per-pixel uncertainties of an image after convolving it with a 2D kernel?

Tags: measurement-error, convolution

I have one 2D image (let's call it "model image"), which is generated by evaluating a particular analytic model for each of its pixels. Since this is just a simple analytic model, there is no error/uncertainty associated with its pixels. I also have a 2D image (let's call it "kernel"), which is an observation of a star and it looks like a 2D Gaussian blob. This kernel, since it is an observation, has error/uncertainty associated with each of its pixels.

Then I convolve the model image with the kernel. What is the error on each of the pixels in the convolved model image?

Thank you.

Comment: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/2515-5172/abe8df#rnaasabe8dfs3[](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/2515-5172/abe8df#rnaasabe8dfs3) This should answer your question.